# Windows batch file - bin not recognized

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a CrossWorks project I am trying to compile, however, there is a batch file that includes a 'bin' command that my system does not recognize. The line throwing the error:

```
bin -ifile %1.bin -ofile temp.bin -pad 0xFF -size 0x4000
```

And the error itself:

```
'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Am I missing a statement or is there an additional package I need to install to run this command? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The file `bin.exe` file must sit in the current directory (the directory from where you run your script) or it must be in the system path. Search your hard drive for `bin.exe`. If it doesn't exist, then you likely need to install something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no executable in the search path called bin.exe (or bin.bat, or bin.cmd).

You either need to add the folder containing bin.exe to the search path, or you need to fully qualify it in the batch file.

I am not familiar with CrossWorks, but I bet if you looked in it's installation folder, or it's contents, you'll find bin.exe.  For example, if CrossWorks is installed into C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Crossworks change your batch file to be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CrossWorks\bin.exe" -ifile %1.bin -ofile temp.bin -pad 0xFF -size 0x4000
```

Alternatively you can go into the system properties, Advanced, Environment Variables and add it to the end of the PATH variable.

Or, you could at the top of your batch file add the following line:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Crossworks
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Smythe! Crossworks didn't have the bin.exe, but I was able to get it from the project's developer.